# Keep checkbox checked AND only check 1 checkbox per group

Tags: forms, checkbox

I'm looking to combine two things:

a) ensure that when a checkbox is checked, it remains checked after submit, AND

b) only allow one  checkbox per group (e.g. the one below) be allowed to be checked at once. I can't use radio buttons unfortunately!

I can do a) & b) in isolation but unfortunately can't seem to combine them! Please help?

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="low" <?php if(isset($_POST['a'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="mid" <?php if(isset($_POST['b'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="hi" <?php if(isset($_POST['c'])) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>/>
</form>
```

Comment: are you fine with using JS?

Comment: Yes, JS is okay by me :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, I was able to create a function that will allow only one checkbox to be clicked at a time.

```
$('.check').click(function(){
if($('.check:checked').length == 1){
    $('.check:not(:checked)').attr('disabled',true);
}
else if($('.check:checked').length == 0){
    $('.check:not(:checked)').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});

<p>Check a box</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t0h4pmw4/)

Comment: Well you have to do that with PHP which you said you could do already.